# ls -ltr command in UNIX and Linux - Behaviour

Tags: linux, unix, ls

Why does ls -ltr show different total? We have same files in both unix and linux environment
please refer BELOW

UNIX

```
> ls -ltr /A/B/C/
total 2140
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       14415 May 30  2007 A.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       11445 May 30  2007 B.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       13443 May 30  2007 C.cab
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo      614429 May 30  2007 D.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo      384763 May 30  2007 E.cab
```

LINUX

```
> ls -ltr /A/B/C/
total 1024
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       14415 May 30  2007 A.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       11445 May 30  2007 B.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       13443 May 30  2007 C.cab
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo      614429 May 30  2007 D.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo      384763 May 30  2007 E.cab
```

Comment: _Which_ UNIX? System V? Mac OS X? AIX? Solaris? Some-or-other-BSD? ...

Answer (score 1):

That's the number of blocks used on the filesystem. The `info` utility on GNU/Linux machines will explain it in more detail. Run

```
info coreutils ls
```

I can only assume that your UNIX provides something similiar. To get a more human readable output run

```
ls -ltrh
```

Thus I presume that your GNU/Linux and UNIX machine use different blocksizes on their fs.

Comment: Any way to compare the files (just count) of two different Environment? 

I can run a script on both servers to find the count, and compare.

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: In the example I provided, there are five files under /A/B/C/ in both Unix and server. 

I have other directories under A, and B. I need to check the number of files in both unix and linux servers.

Comment: I have no clue, what Unix means to you. But to count the files in a directory under GNU/Linux run `ls | wc -l`. If you need subdirectories too, try `find . -type f | wc -l`.